# For loop inside of for loop cant seem to figure it out

Tags: javascript

I have a rather simple for loop inside of a for loop but I just cant get it to work like intended. 
The shown code is supposed to be a filter . 
eTags gets me the p element I want to filter. 
I have several buttons/filterwords and "activated" gets me those if they are clicked. 
Now in the second if condition I look if the p element contains the textContent of the Filter Button. 
It works for one filter but if activated > 2 it does not. 
In the second for loop iteration it hides the one element it made visible in the first iteration. 
I know Im stupid but any help would be appreciated !

```js
let eTags = document.querySelectorAll(".placeDescription33");
let activated = document.getElementsByClassName('activexyz');

for (let n = 0; n < eTags.length; n++) {
  let vater2 = eTags[n].parentNode;
  let grossvater2 = vater2.parentNode;

  if (activated.length === 0) {
    eTags[n].style.visibility = "visible";
    grossvater2.style.display = "inline"
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < activated.length; i++) {

    let textCont = activated[i].textContent.trim();

    if (eTags[n].textContent.contains(textCont)) {
      eTags[n].style.visibility = "visible";
      grossvater2.style.display = "inline"
    } else if (!(eTags[n].textContent.contains(textCont))) {
      eTags[n].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      grossvater2.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is missing from your demo.

Comment: Yes it does jump into the condition. Its a logical error.
I think the html would only make it more complicated. PlaceDescription is a simple p element. And active is added to the button after clicking so it changes its color.

Comment: I've never seen `.contains()` on anything but `classList`. (Though apparently you can use it on `DOM` nodes, too). Are you sure you can use this with `textContent`? Try [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your second loop, you are activating the right ones and deactivating the wrong ones. So if you turn one on in another iteration, it will get turned off... I'd simply turn everything off before hand.

```
for (let n = 0; n < eTags.length; n++) {
  let vater2 = eTags[n].parentNode;
  let grossvater2 = vater2.parentNode;

  if (activated.length === 0) {
    eTags[n].style.visibility = "visible";
    grossvater2.style.display = "inline"
  }else{
    eTags[n].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    grossvater2.style.display = 'none';
    for (let i = 0; i < activated.length; i++) {

      let textCont = activated[i].textContent.trim();

      if (eTags[n].textContent.contains(textCont)) {
        eTags[n].style.visibility = "visible";
        grossvater2.style.display = "inline"
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats it ! My head was already smoking ! 
Have a nice day kind Sir ! I will accept your answer !